# Button not showing when condition is met

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have an object called formData that I am using with `useState()`.

Whenever a field is changed in the form, `formData` gets updated like so:

`setFormData({...formData, [field.id]: field.value})`

I want the button at the bottom of the form to change when all the required fields have been filled out, which means all the values in `formData` are not null.  (By default, when the object is initialized all the values are null).  So i have the following:

```
{ (Object.values(formData).filter(value => value !== null) == true) ? (
    <Button
        Size='w-full'
        Caption='Submit & Continue'
        AdditionalClasses='block text-center'
        Type={'primary'}
    />
) : (
    <Button
        Size='w-full'
        Caption='Please fill in the above form to continue'
        AdditionalClasses='block justify-center'
        Disabled={0}
        OnClick={test}
        Type={'disabled'}
    />
)}
```

However the button isn't changing even though the conditions have been met and the values are not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this will always return `true` because `Object.values` returnes an array:

```js
Object.values(formData).filter(value => value !== null) == true
```

Consider doing:

```js
Object.values(formData).filter(value => value !== null).length
```

Comment: Aha, coming from PHP an empty array is false so thats where I was going wrong! Thanks!